# How to get the output from a kyword using robot.api?

Tags: python, robotframework

I hope you can help me, I am quite stuck with this issue :(

I am trying to create all the tests using the robot api with python, I followed the example in the documentation, but I need to capture the output from a keyword and I dont find how can I do it

I tried as usual in rf-ride syntax:

```
 test.keywords.create('${greps}=  grep file', args=['log.txt', 'url:',  'encoding_errors=ignore'])
```

It says: No keyword with name '${grep}=          grep file' found.

I tried:

```
output = test.keywords.create('grep file', args=['log.txt', 'url:',  'encoding_errors=ignore'])
```

but the variable *output* is having just the keyword name, not the output from kw

I dont know where to look for more info, all the examples are creating kw which dont return any value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `test.keywords.create(...)` doesn't *call* the keyword, it merely creates one to be called later. If you want the results to be assigned to a variable, use the `assign` attribute when calling `create`. This argument takes a list of variable names.

For example, given this line in plain text format:

```
${greps}=    grep file    log.txt    url:    encoding_errors=ignore
```

... you would create it like this using the API:

```
test.keywords.create('grep file', 
                     args=['log.txt', 'url:',  'encoding_errors=ignore'],
                     assign=['${greps}'])
```

Comment: great!!, thanks a lot, it is exactly what i needed :),

Comment: How to call this keyword and receive value? @sis

Comment: @Chetan: I don't understand the question. This answer relates to creating a test case in code. This code doesn't create a keyword, it calls the `grep file` keyword. `test.keywords.create()` doesn't create a new keyword, it adds an existing keyword to the list of keywords (`test.keywords`) of an existing in-memory test (`test`).