# Dynamic test cases in Robotframework - How to assign return value from a keyword to a variable?

Tags: python, robotframework

I found a way to create dynamic test cases in Robot framework using below post, and its working good.

[Robot framework: Is there a way to write dynamic test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876885/robot-framework-is-there-a-way-to-write-dynamic-test-cases)

However, the problem I am facing is with assigning the return value of the keyword to a variable. I could not find the syntax for it using dynamic format. I tried some options, but none of them worked.

For example, if I want to write in Robot Framework:

```
${Results}= | SSHLibrary.Execute Command | pwd
Log | ${Results}
```

**Attempt 1:**
I wrote in the dynamic syntax as:

```
test.keywords.create('${Results}=       Execute Command', args=['pwd'])
test.keywords.create('Log', args=['${Results}'])
```

This gives me error:

```
No keyword with name '${Results}=       Execute Command' found.
```

**Attempt 2:**
Then I tried:

```
Results = test.keywords.create('Execute Command', args=['pwd'])
test.keywords.create('Log', args=[Results])
```

It just prints the command, not the output.

[image: Log snapshot]

Pls advise!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the output from a kyword using robot.api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973452/how-to-get-the-output-from-a-kyword-using-robot-api)

Comment: This is what exactly I am looking for. Thank you!